# Can I define a Java Home filesystem for my sbt project in the project/build.properties configuration file?

Tags: java, android, scala, sbt

For compatibility reasons with Android plugin for sbt and Scala, I have to use an old version of sbt, working with a JDK of a version not upper than 1.8.X....
My project/build.properties contents is,

```
`sbt.version=0.13.18
java.home=/path/to/my/jdk1.8.0_202/jre`
```

The result is that first line works, but the seccond (line for the supposed Java Home configuration...) doesn't make my desired effect
¿Are there a command (for project/build.properties or perhaps another configuration place...), in what could I define de JDK version **for working in conjunction with** my sbt 0.13...?

I tried to put in my build.sbt,

`val java8Version: Option[File] = Option(file("/path/to/my/jdk1.8.0_202/jre"))

javaHome := java8Version`

But, when I try,
`~/path/to/my/project$ sbt`

The output when sbt starts is,
`[info] Loading global plugins from /path/to/my/.sbt/0.13/plugins WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by sbt.ivyint.ErrorMessageAuthenticator$ (file:/path/to/my/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.7/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.18/ivy-0.13.18.jar) to field java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of sbt.ivyint.ErrorMessageAuthenticator$ WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release [info] Loading project definition from /path/to/my/project/project [info] Set current project to project (in build file:/path/to/my/project/)`

And doesn't appear any information abot my Java Home supposedly configured, like does when I don't configure anything

`[info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Debian Java 11.0.15)`

This line doesn't appear when I put the mentioned "sbt.version=0.13.18" in the mentioned /project/build.properties. Instead, appears the "An illegal reflective access operation has occurred" warning messages upperly cited, that I suspect is for the "Debian Java 11.0.5" **uncompatible** JDK version for my "0.13.18" sbt version................

How can I make the "jdk1.8.0_2022" JDK version would be used when my "0.13.18" sbt starts?

Comment: Java version should be defined outside of SBT. Via JAVA_HOME for instance. Or directly on the CLI when running SBT with something like `sbt -java-home=...` (not sure about the name of the argument, documentation should help).

Comment: Note that the version SBT runs can be different than the version your project runs/compiles for though.

Comment: Thank you very much, -Gaél,
sbt --java-home /path/to/my/jkd1.8.0_202 worked perfect for me!!
Kisses, zanks a lot, :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.